# Can I use wildcards in oc exec commands?

Tags: openshift, aws-cli

I am trying to run remote commands on the openshift pods to delete some files in certain directory and the below command works:

```
oc exec mypod -i  -t -- rm -f /tmp/mydir/1.txt
```

However, i am unable to use wildcards e.g *.txt to remove all .txt files. The command with wildcards does not give any errors but doesn't delete any files.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The following command worked:

```
oc exec mypod -i -t -- find /tmp/mydir -type f -name '*.txt' -delete
```

Hopefully it will be useful to someone else.

Comment: A key thing being to quote, using single quotes, the portion of the command with the wildcard in it, else the wildcard will be expanded based on what is in your current directory on the local box.